# Get error when install node-sqlite3 on windows 8

Tags: node.js, sqlite

Good day for everyone!

My OS: WINDOWS 8
Installed software: VS2012 expess, Python 2.7.5, Windows8SDK, node 0.10.17, npm 1.3.8

I got error:

> C:\Users\sapa\worksapce\node-sqlite3\build\Release\obj\global_intermediate\sqlite-autoconf-3071700\sqlite3.c(606):
>   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdarg.h': No such file
>   or directory
>   [C:\Users\sapa\worksapce\node-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]

when I installed module node-sqlite3 on my OS.
For installing I used command *npm install node-sqlite3* and got this error. After that I used installing from source:

I cloned source from github https://github.com/developmentseed/node-sqlite3

then I used command *node-gyp configure* and got

```
C:\Users\sapa\worksapce\node-sqlite3>node-gyp configure
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@0.10.9
gyp info using node@0.10.17 | win32 | x64
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.17/node-v0.10.17.tar.gz
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.17/node-v0.10.17.tar.gz
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.17/node.lib
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.17/x64/node.lib
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.17/node.lib
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.17/x64/node.lib
gyp info spawn python
gyp info spawn args [ 'C:\\Users\\sapa\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\nod
e-gyp\\gyp\\gyp',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-G',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=auto',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\sapa\\worksapce\\node-sqlite3\\build\\config.g
ypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\sapa\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\nod
e-gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\sapa\\.node-gyp\\0.10.17\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\sapa\\.node-gyp\\0.10.17',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\sapa\\worksapce\\node-sqlite
3',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\sapa\\worksapce\\node-sqlite3\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info ok
```

then *node-gyp build* and got:

```
C:\Users\sapa\worksapce\node-sqlite3>node-gyp build
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@0.10.9
gyp info using node@0.10.17 | win32 | x64
gyp info spawn msbuild
gyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' ]
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
  unpack_sqlite_dep
  sqlite3.c
C:\Users\sapa\worksapce\node-sqlite3\build\Release\obj\global_intermediate\sqli
te-autoconf-3071700\sqlite3.c(606): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file
: 'stdarg.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\sapa\worksapce\node-sqlite3\b
uild\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\sapa\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod
e_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:
12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Users\\sapa\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\n
ode-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\sapa\worksapce\node-sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.17
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.9
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Cloud you help me in this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to build a 64 bit installation (Platform=x64).
A 32 bit node v0.10.22 with npm install sqlite3 works for me on windows 7

Answer (score 0):

set like this， and then have a try:

`npm config set msvs_version 2012
npm config set python c:/python/python.exe`